# Xcode & Objective-C: Is tookbox SDK able to make a SIP video call between a video entry-phone and an iOS Device?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sip

Someone knows it the TookBox SKD is able to make a SIP video call between a video entry-phone and an iOS Device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you use WebRTC then definitely yes.